# Why 'Model_name' object is not iterable?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Why I got the error { TypeError at /4 'Model_name' object is not iterable }
for this code in my

**destinations.html**

```
                        {% for dest in dests %}
                        <div>{{dest.name}}</div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

I don't know what have I mistaken

```
                   urlpatterns=[
                         path('',views.index,name='index'),
                         path('<int:destinations_id>', views.destinations, name='destinations'),
                        ]
```

**views.py**

when I was fetching all rows of Model on template by "dests=Destination.objects.all()" than there was no error for same "destinations.html", but I want only row of perticular id on template so I'm using "get_object_or_404".

```
                    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
                    from .models import Destination

                    def destinations(request, destinations_id):
                        dests = get_object_or_404(Destination, pk=destinations_id)
                        return render(request, 'destinations.html', {'dests':dests})
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use the for loop, because get_object_or_404 get only 1 model destination...

if you want get a list of all destinations you can use

> dests = Destination.objects.all()

So now you can use for loop...

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I understood what you said and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs because you are getting only one object instance by using
**get_object_or_404 get**
No need to use loop you can say directly

```
<div>{{dest.name}}</div>
```

but if you use

```
dests = Destination.objects.all()
```

then you can use loop as

```
                        {% for dest in dests %}
                        <div>{{dest.name}}</div>
                        {% endfor %}
```